# WebClient and proxy server (Ntlm auth maybe?)

Tags: proxy, webclient

Having some issues connecting to internet from an application where a customer is using a proxy server.
The following code seems to work most other customers, including those that use proxies.

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wc.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy

wc.Proxy.Credentials = wc.Credentials
Dim responseBytes As Byte() = wc.DownloadData("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

Error is:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (407) Proxy
>   Authentication Required.

Previously this same way of connecting did work using their old proxy server, now it doesn't work. 
The customer has recently changed proxy server to one that uses NTLM authentication, so I guess this could be the issue.

Any ideas how I should be connecting any differently to above example?

Thanks,
Mike G

Comment: Even if anyone has some code that does this kind of thing but a different way i'd be interrested to see it, i'm running out of ideas at the moment.
Has anyone out there got some good examples of "how to connect to internet" code that is known to work in many different scenarios, i.e. with/without proxy etc...

Comment: Forget to mention that this is in a Windows forms app (i.e. Have windows user logged in to get credentials from)